# How can I get samples when running go with pkg/profile enabled?

Tags: go, pprof

I have the following in my main block:

```
func main() {
    defer profile.Start().Stop()

    fmt.Println("running version", version, "built on", date)
    fmt.Println()
    cmd.Execute()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}
```

where `cmd` is a cobra subcommand. I do a go build, and then I run the binary. I can see that it generates a `pprof` file:

```
2018/09/13 18:43:26 profile: cpu profiling enabled, /tmp/profile705487093/cpu.pprof
... output deleted ...
2018/09/13 18:43:31 profile: cpu profiling disabled, /tmp/profile705487093/cpu.pprof
```

Then I'm trying to analyze it, using:

```
go tool pprof /root/code/debug/evented /tmp/profile705487093/cpu.pprof
```

But when pprof opens, I see this:

```
File: evented
Type: cpu
Time: Sep 13, 2018 at 6:43pm (UTC)
Duration: 5.49s, Total samples = 0
```

In case it helps, I'm running `go version go1.11 linux/amd64` on a `Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS`. Not sure whether it matters, but I'm trying to inspect the pprof output on a DigitalOcean droplet.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: This Go blog post details exactly how to use `pprof`: https://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: Thanks, but that is not directly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking a bit through the comments of the profile pkg, I managed to get some samples, by doing this:

```
runtime.SetCPUProfileRate(5000)
```

before calling the `defer profile.Start().Stop()` line.

Comment: That's shouldn't be the case, default `hz` value is `100`, which should actually acquire samples, than what you have set.

Comment: with the default of 100 i have 0, both on my mac and on digital ocean